# change button position in scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, position

I have ScrollView and in this scroll view I have buttons and one table. I want to change position buttons and size table when my form was loaded. 
For example, if the table is made up of 5 cells, buttons position need to change on 200 by y (down). And table need to has height = height_table + 200.

My code:

```
var yPosition: CGFloat = 0;
var scrollViewContentSize: CGFloat = 505;
var names = ["first","second","third","fourth","fifth"]

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.yPosition += 40 * CGFloat(names.count)
    self.scrollViewContentSize += 40 * CGFloat(names.count)
    self.scrlMain.contentSize = CGSize(width: 320,height: self.scrollViewContentSize)

    let btnY1: CGFloat = 40 * CGFloat(names.count) + 467
    btn1.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 210, y: btnY1)

    let btnY2: CGFloat = 44 * CGFloat(names.count) + 386
    btn2.frame = CGRectMake(26, btnY2, 46, 30)

    let btnY3: CGFloat = 44 * CGFloat(names.count) + 427
    btn3.frame = CGRectMake(26, btnY3, 46, 30)

    var framelb: CGRect = lb.frame
    framelb.origin.y += 40 * CGFloat(names.count)
    framelb.origin.x = 110
    lb.frame = framelb

    tableView.contentOffset.y += 40 * CGFloat(names.count)
    tableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 304, height: tableView.contentOffset.y)
}
```

What did I do wrong?

[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Clh.png)

[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1tc1.png)

I tried to add func setControlsPosition, but nothing happened.

Code:

```
func setControlsPosition(){
tableView.contentOffset.y += 40 * CGFloat(names.count)
tableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 304, height: tableView.contentOffset.y)

let lblY: CGFloat = tableView.frame.origin.y + tableView.frame.size.height+10 //10 for spacing between tableView and label
lb.frame = CGRectMake(26, lblY, 46, 30)

let btn1Y: CGFloat = lb.frame.origin.y + lb.frame.size.height + 10 // Spacing between label and button
btn1Y.frame = CGRectMake(26, btn1Y, 46, 30)
}

//This is code work well
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.yPosition += 40 * CGFloat(names.count)
    self.scrollViewContentSize += 40 * CGFloat(names.count)
    self.scrlMain.contentSize = CGSize(width: 320,height: self.scrollViewContentSize)
//This function is performed, but nothing changes
    setControlsPosition()
}
```

I checked, names.count = 5 in the function setControlsPosition. It is correct.

Comment: You have a scrollview, and in this scrollView a tableView?

Comment: Can you explain? You have a scrollview , with a table (scrollview) and a button? The first scrollview is horizontal?

Comment: I have Scrollview and in this scrollview there are tableview and buttons.

Comment: @Dim please share any screen shot, as you'r question is confusing with what you have implemented. Why have you taken the constants with buttons( btnY1). Do you want to display all the button at the end of tableview?

Comment: I added screens. Yes, I want to display all the buttons at the end of tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous control as a reference to define the position other control

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    setControlsPosition()

    self.scrollViewContentSize = button3.frame.origin.y + button3.frame.size.height + 10
    self.scrlMain.contentSize = CGSize(width: 320,height: self.scrollViewContentSize)
}

func setControlsPosition(){
    tableView.contentOffset.y += 40 * CGFloat(names.count)
    tableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 304, height: tableView.contentOffset.y)

    let lblY: CGFloat = tableView.frame.origin.y + tableView.frame.size.height+10 //10 for spacing between tableView and label
    lb.frame = CGRectMake(26, lblY, 46, 30)

    let btn1Y: CGFloat = lb.frame.origin.y + lb.frame.size.height + 10 // Spacing between label and button
    btn1Y.frame = CGRectMake(26, btn1Y, 46, 30)
}
```

Please understand and then implement.

Similarly you can do for all you'r other controls. After setting all other controls you can define the scroll contentsize as per the last control's position.

All this thing can be more simpler with Autolayout. Try to use that.

Hope this may help you

Comment: I added setControlsPosition() to viewDidAppear, but nothing happened.

Comment: Debug the code and check whether it's working as per you'r requirement. I had just given an example or else I need to look you'r complete code

Comment: @Dim join this for further discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110895/mainting-controls

Comment: I added the new code in the question. Sorry, I must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk there.